# AngualrJS - Ionic - How to start an async process after the popup closes?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, popup, angular-promise

I am writing an app with Ionic 1.3 and Angular 1.5.

I am using the $ionicPopup service in my app.

```
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: getShowPopupTitle(),
            buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function () {
                    processData();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'CANCEL',
                type: 'button-default',
                onTap: function () {
                }
            }]
        });
```

I am having digest loop and view updating issues with my app so this is what I want to try:

After the user clicks OK and the popup is gone from the view and the scope then I want to call the remaining async processes.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: IMO you should fix the digest loop issue instead of going around it.
can you share the code snippet that cause the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `.then` callback?

```
    var popup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: getShowPopupTitle(),
        buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function () {
                processData();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'CANCEL',
            type: 'button-default',
            onTap: function () {
            }
        }]
    });
    popup.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

If you need more time after the popup closes, then you can use the $timeout service.

```
popup.then(function(data){
    popup.close();
    $timeout(function(){
        // do your thing here...
    });
});
```